# Sorting String Anagrams java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

Question: 
Write a method to sort an array of strings so that all the anagrams are next to each other.

I am trying to test the methods in the main. When I compile it gives me this error:

Error:(29, 28) java: non-static method sortChars(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context

### How can I fix this error?

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class StringAnagrams implements Comparator{

```
public  String sortChars(String s){

    char[] content = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(content);

    return new String(content);
}

public  int compare(String s1, String s2){

    return sortChars(s1).compareTo(sortChars(s2));
}

public static void main (String [] args){


    String st1 = "tree";
    String st2 = "eert";

    System.out.println(sortChars(st1));
    System.out.println(sortChars(st2));

    System.out.println(compare(st1,st2));


}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: make all methods static

Comment: If you google the error message, you get all kinds of good information. You might try that next time.

Comment: Please give some input-output example.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to add static keyword to your method.

```
public static String sortChars(String s){
char[] content = s.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(content);

return new String(content);
}
```